# Why am I getting a 'list index out of range' error?

Tags: python, wordnet

I was trying to implement the `wordnet` module by **NLTK**. But I keep getting the error `list index out of range`. What is wrong with my code? Please help me.

*My code:*

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

s=wordnet.synsets('worse')
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i].lemmas()[i].name())
```

*Error:*

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what makes you think there are as many items in `lemmas()` as there are in `s`?

Comment: How many lemmas are there per element?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what a `lemmas()` does actually.

Comment: Furthermore: avoid indexing when possible (90% of the time or more in python)

Comment: @Abhishek Well then how are we supposed to help? Wouldn’t figuring out what it does (ideally before you use it) be the best place to start?

Answer (score 0):

the list returned from `s[i].lemmas()` has less items in it than the original `s` list.  To fix this, iterate over the lists directly:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

s = wordnet.synsets('worse')
for w in s:
    for l in w.lemmas():
        print(l.name())
```